# Assign Host IP-Address to Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, scrapy

Is it possible to assign the ip address of the host system to a docker container?

Context:
I want to access my AWS Elasticsearch Service (ES) Domain by using the [Elasticsearch-Pipline](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch) for Srcapy. The ES domain is only accessible for certain IP addresses. Currently I get an "connection refused error" when running the scrapy spider. As far as I understand a docker container gets a dynamic IP address (which then is not amongst the allowed IPs). As the host's IP Address is allowed to access the ES Domain I want to assign this IP to the docker container running the scrapy spider.

Currently I try the described using Docker for Windwos on my own machine. A step further I want run the container on an AWS EC2 Instance.

current settings.py for my scrapy project:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline' : 300
}

ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER = 'https://testdomain.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com' 
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT = 443
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'testindex'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'testtype'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I follow, why not publish the ports you need to access from outside of docker?

Comment: apparently my configuration was faulty. Now I get an error which maybe is not about IP addresses [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670408/accesing-aws-elasticsearch-service-from-scrapy-crawler). But to clarify my question: My ES domain is only accessible for e.g. 99.999.999.99 (which also would by the IP of the docker host). So I have to make sure that I still access my ES domain with IP 99.999.999.99 from inside the docker container.

Comment: That could still be handled by publishing the needed ports (containers can connect out to the host and back into another container). But, if you want to communicate between containers, it's preferred to use a common user created docker network.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
docker container create --net host ...
```

will do it for you.